# Is destroying people's stuff worth it?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've been happily smashing my way through stacks of boxes and barrels so far, and while I find the process mildly enjoyable (about on par with popping bubble wrap), I can't help but notice that the rewards are paltry.  On average thus far, I seem to be ending up with 15-20 gold, if anything at all.  It slows me down to find ALL the crates in an area, and I can't help but wonder if I'd be better off just running past these items and braining monsters for their loot instead.

Do the rewards for breaking people's stuff scale up as I progress, or is this even worth the effort?  Will it always be gold, or can I find other useful/valuable items by smashing crates and barrels?

Comment: I am only level 4 but I have only seen gold.

Comment: I can't say if it gets any better. But keep in mind that sometimes secret things are hiding behind crates and barrels. If you have the Detect Hidden ability I wouldn't worry too much about it since these places will show up on your minimap...but if you don't have that ability, keep smashing :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question.

Destructibles have two main purposes in KoA.

First, like so many Zelda games before it, it's *always* worthwhile to run around smashing pots, barrels, and everything else because someone stashed money in them. There's no reason to *not* take this free money, especially since gold doesn't take up any inventory space.

The second, is that destructibles have a tendency to hide chests and other interactable objects. In this case, the piddling amounts of gold you might glean from the destruction isn't the focus - the phat loots in the chests are. If you're unwilling to hunt down these boxes, you risk missing out on something much better, *especially* if you've got Detect Hidden (which gives greater chance for gold from destroyed objects)

The problem that you're running into, is that it's *tedious* to run around and make sure that every crate is smashed. So my solution? Stop running around smashing barrels. If you're investing into Archery, use your bow. It'll auto-target the destructibles *and* it shoots much faster than you can swing your melee weapons.

I thought the bow was the go-to choice to fight the barrel infestation. And then I found these bad boys.

[image]

Chakram's are ranged AoE weapons of awesome. All you have to do is get marginally close to your target, then tap a button and they *all* break.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:** Elapsed time: 1 click.
[image]

The charged moves are especially useful, and even investing only a single point will net you enough AoE to clear entire rooms (of barrels ***and*** enemies) with ease.

[And where would I be without an appropriate picture to demonstrate the storied tradition of protagonist-on-crate violence‽](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v95xj.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I don't have a better swath of barrels to showcase destroying. I already broke them all when I found out how awesome chakrams were in the first place. :3

Comment: And if you go Finesse, "Shadow Flare" is a low mana cost spell that will take out an entire group of crates at once.

Comment: The other part of the question is, do they always drop low amounts of gold?  Or are there some boxes that contain other things?  Is the amount of gold going to change, or will it always be ~25?

Comment: @agent86 anecdotal experience would seem to indicate that it does grow upwards - I'm getting 30-40 gold in some groups of boxes, now.

Comment: I've got those Chakrams as well, and I'm playing dual class mage/thief, so I may dump some points into that tree.  I like them a bit better than bow and arrow, and the box breaking abilities are a plus...